# Exhange calendars synced/overlayed on webpage?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, outlook

I have been trying to better organize information in my workplace by uploading various users' exchange calendars to a public webpage. SharePoint has potentially useful calendar overlay integration with Outlook; however, it doesn't seem like it's possible to sync multiple Outlook calendars to a master SharePoint online calendar. I'm a rookie in the SharePoint world, so I might be missing something.

So far, I am able to connect the calendar to Outlook desktop client, but not visa versa, so calendars are not visible to the public webpage. Using the "Calendar Overlay," I am able to connect an Exchange calendar, but it gives me the following error when trying to load the calendar:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic
>   Realm="".(8d4bc19e-809d-8000-e01b2c302846e9e1-8000-e01b-2c302846e9e1)

I have also provided the error in image as seen below:

[image: Error]

Research on the site and others leads me to believe that this sort of integration isn't supported by SharePoint. Am I approaching this the wrong way? I was really excited to use this overlay capability, but I'm starting to doubt this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The error "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'" occurs because the ability to use the calendar overlay in a SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server calendar that is retrieved from Exchange Online **isn't supported**. We cannot use the calendar overlay to let the Exchange Online calendar display in the SharePoint Online.

For more information, please refer to [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2997170).

As a workaround, you may need to create your own customization calendar solution or use the third-party tool.